# Z3 v4.1 does not accept negative integers as input

Tags: z3

I have installed Z3 version 4.1 and I attempt to use it programmatically in a java application. My application is communicating with the Z3 via ProcessBuilder. The version of Z3 is verified as 4.1 by using the /version command line argument.

However, Z3 does not accept negative constants as part of expressions. When I attempt to provide a negative integers I get the following message:

```
(error "line 4 column 31: unknown constant -1")
```

This is the input I provide to Z3:

```
(push)
(declare-fun y () Int )
(define-fun x () Int y )
(assert (and (<= y 1000) (>= y -1) ) )
(assert (= x 42) )
(check-sat)
(pop)
```

I am using the following arguments to instantiate the Z3:

```
Z3 /smt2 /in /t:2
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `(- 1)`. See bottom of page 38 in http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2017-07-18.pdf

Comment: So what you are saying is, that the semantics have changed since version 4.8.1, correct? In version 4.8.4 negative integers are accepted in the format I have provided in my question.

Comment: Well, version 4.8.1 is newer than 4.1; looks like at some point z3 started supporting the `-1` syntax; but this is an extension to the SMTLib standard. Unless you've some other reason, I'd recommend using the `(- 1)` syntax that's guaranteed by the SMTLib standard and is portable across solvers. (For instance, I'm pretty sure CVC4 will not accept `-1`.)